# Gerrit gets format-patch from command line?

Tags: git, patch, gerrit

Given a change-id, how can I download the format-patch from command line?

I look through gerrit commands but cannot find a proper command to do this. Nor I find a command to query commit-id from change-id.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If all you have is the Change-id you can use a tool like [git-review](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/git-review) to download the latest patch-set of the change-set and then generate the patch file:

```
git-review -d I0e5b4d5271e9de8f1187a29e642afacae57ddbe7
git format-patch HEAD~
```

Or, if you can get access to the change number and want to just use Git:

```
git fetch ssh://user@gerrit-server.yourcompany.com:29418/path/to/project refs/changes/71/20531/2
git format-patch FETCH_HEAD~
```

The `git fetch` command above can be copy-pasted from the upper-right corner (the "download" drop-down) on the change-set's Gerrit web UI page.